# MVC route URL not containing parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm attempting to wrap my head around .NET MVC5 routing.

I've got a form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProductsCheaperThan", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <input type="text" name="comparisonPrice" />
    <button type="submit">Search!</button>
}
```

And I've got a controller `Home` and an action `ProductsCheaperThan` which takes a parameter `comparisonPrice`

```
public ActionResult ProductsCheaperThan(decimal comparisonPrice)
{
    ViewBag.FilterPrice = comparisonPrice;
    var resultSet = new ProductService().GetProductsCheaperThan(comparisonPrice);
    return View(resultSet);
}
```

This posts the value in the input (let's suppose that the value I'm posting is `20`) back to my action, and correctly routes me to `~/Home/ProductsCheaperThan`. The problem is, I'd like to be routed to `~/Home/ProductsCheaperThan/20`

I'd like to do this so that if somebody bookmarks the page they don't end up getting an error when they revisit the page.

I thought that adding something like:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ProductsCheaperThan",
    url: "Home/ProductsCheaperThan/{comparisonPrice}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ProductsCheaperThan", comparisonPrice = 20 }
);
```

might work, and I have one solution to my problem which changes the form to a GET

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ProductsCheaperThan", "Home", FormMethod.Get))
```

and produces a URL of `~/Home/ProductsCheaperThan?comparisonPrice=20`, but that uses a query string instead, and isn't exactly what I was aiming for.

Can anybody help me get my URL right?

Answer (score 1):

You should add `[HttpPost]` attribute to your action

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ProductsCheaperThan(decimal comparisonPrice)
{
    ViewBag.FilterPrice = comparisonPrice;
    var resultSet = new ProductService().GetProductsCheaperThan(comparisonPrice);
    return View(resultSet);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work I'm afraid, for two reasons. One, the URL I end up with is still `http://localhost:1959/Home/ProductsCheaperThan` rather than `http://localhost:1959/Home/ProductsCheaperThan/20`, and secondly, anyone coming back to that URL from a bookmark won't be able to get the page as they'd be hitting it with a GET rather than a POST.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use JQuery -

```
<div>
    <input type="text" name="comparisonPrice" id="comparisonPrice" />
    <button type="button" id="Search">Search!</button>
</div>

@section scripts{
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $("#Search").click(function () {
                window.location = "@Url.Action("PriceToCompare", "Home")" + "/" + $("#comparisonPrice").val();
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Above script will result in - `http://localhost:1655/PriceToCompare/Home/123`

Answer (score 0):

I think you can specify your route values using an overload:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "Account", new { comparisonPrice= "20" }))
{
...
}`

Comment: That would always result in `~/Home/ProductsCheaperThan/20` (it would never reflect the value in the textbox!)

Comment: Oh sorry about that...
MVC should automatically bind you textbox value to the action method parameter given their names are matched.
Make sure you have [HttpPost] on your method.

I noticed in your route setting you hard-coded controller and action method names in the url. The route url setting should be like:

    url: "{controller}/{action}/{comparisonPrice}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ProductsCheaperThan", comparisonPrice= UrlParameter.Optional }